# Process-to-port mapping with SNMP and/or wmi/wmic in java

Tags: java, wmi, snmp

I'm trying to use SNMP to map outgoing ports on my host computer with the application running on the computer that is responsible for that communication.

When running "netstat -ano" I get access to Protocol, Local Address (with port), Foreign Address (with port), State and PID. But I want to do this entirely without having to execute "cmd" from Java.

By using SNMP OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4 (.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.host.hrSWRun)
I get access to PID (ex. 1704), Name (ex. cmd.exe), Path (ex. C:\Windows\system32) among others.
There is an SNMP OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.6.13 (.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.tcp.tcpConnTable)
that give you access to TCP connection state, local address, local port, remote address, remote port. But NO PID.

So to sum up. My question again: Is there a way to "map" these tables together? Either directly in SNMP with other OID's or in conjunction with WMI / WMIC?

UPDATE: What I want is access to tcpConnectionProcess in TcpConnectionEntry (tcpConnectionTable). This is from RFC 4022.
tcpConnectionProcess has OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.8 (.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.tcp.tcpConnectionTable.tcpConnectionEntry.tcpConnectionProcess)

The strange thing is that I get values from OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7 (.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.tcp.tcpConnectionTable.tcpConnectionEntry.tcpConnectionState)

The main problem here is that in Windows, this table is empty. Probably my lack of knowledge with regards to installation on Windows, but any help would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

It's still true 3 years later: MS doesn't support `tcpListenerTable` or `tcpConnectionTable,` despite RFC4022 being from 2005. It returns the `tcpConnTable` for both these requests, and you need to be set up to handle that, as it's a different OID from the one you requested.

And the data returned isn't 100% reliable. I was using this request to find out when an application started listening on the socket, and it didn't tell me accurately for several minutes.